# Google Chrome marks my .exe that I uploaded to my website as a virus

Tags: google-chrome, virus

I have a personal website that I use for hosting files, etc. It is a .com website, so it isn't a free subdomain (website.000webhost.net, website.x10.mx, etc...)

Because it's a personal domain, the files I upload are password protected, and as such are downloaded roughly 1-2 times a month.

Google chrome takes this as a warning:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? It only does it to .exe files, not a zip file that exclusively contains the .exe.

I realize I can click the arrow and chose "Keep", however my family sometimes downloads stuff from my website and would never remember. Every time they download something I inevitably get a call: "It says it's a virus what do"...

Comment: Another alternative to sharing files between a small group of people (i.e., family) is to use a Dropbox shared folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you can turn off that warning in Chrome, but that's neither advisable nor feasible when it comes to others' PCs. You'll need to purchase a digital certificate and sign your programs to prevent that warning from showing up. If that doesn't help [here's an alternate solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512919).

Comment: How much does that cost / where can I get one?

Comment: There are lots of providers, and I'm sure you can find resellers in your country as well. You can search the net, contact a few and compare the costs.